# How to Use JavaScript code in PHP code

Tags: javascript

I want to know the present location of the user in my application.For that i have to use the

Geolocation code in my PHP code.But i don't know how to use JavaScript code in the PHP code.

The JavaScript code for Geolocation is as follows.

```
      function displayLocation(loc){
      var lat = loc.coords.latitude;
      var lon = loc.coords.longitude;
      }
      function getLocation(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
      }
    $(document).ready(function(){
    getLocation();
    });
```

i want to assign these lat and lon values to my php variables Latitude and longitude.

For that i have to know how to use the JavaScript code in php and how to assign JavaScript
values to php variables.

Let me know if any suggestions to complete this task.

```
              Thanks.......
```

Comment: Just use a `<script>` tag for JS, and escape PHP code where needed with `<?php ?>`

Answer (score 4):

You cannot assign a javascript value to a PHP value because javascript runs on client side and PHP on server side.

You need to send the latitude and longitude values back to the server either with a simple POST/GET action or with ajax.

**Getting user's location:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayLocation(loc){
      var lat = loc.coords.latitude;
      var lon = loc.coords.longitude;
      $("#lat").val(lat);
      $("#lon").val(lon);
    }
    function getLocation(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation);
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
      getLocation();
    });
</script>
```

**Putting location values into a form then submit it to server side:**

```
<form action="coordinates.php" method="post" id="cform">
  Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" id="lat" value=""><br>
  Longitude: <input type="text" name="lon" id="lon" value=""><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send data">
</form>
```

**Processing user's location in PHP from the form:**

```
<?php
  $lat = $_POST["lat"];
  $lon = $_POST["lon"];
  echo "Your location is: " . $lat . ", " . $lon;
?>
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xuM86/1/)

**Ajax example for the code above:**

```
$.post("coordinates.php", $("#cform").serialize(), function(result){
    // code executed here when we get response from the server
    alert(result);
});
```

Comment: But when sending javascript values to the php file using POST/GET action the page will not be standing stable and the values will not be printed .......what is the problem

Comment: If you dont want to reload the whole page you need to send the location data back to server using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: Can u please send me the code for the ajax because i don't know about ajax any thing........